# Webpack bundle-loader trying to load non-existent file

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to use Webpack's [bundle-loader](https://github.com/webpack/bundle-loader) to asynchronously load Pikaday for a datepicker component (I only want to load Pikaday on those pages that use it). It seems that I've managed to get the build working correctly -- an additional JS file is generated that includes Pikaday, and my base bundle does not -- but the code that bundle-loader generates to request the new file looks for an incorrect URL.

The relevant code looks like this:

My Datepicker component imports Pikaday with bundle-loader: `import pikadayLoader from 'bundle!pikaday';`. Then it uses that like so

```
pikadayLoader(Pikaday => {
  this.picker = new Pikaday({
    field: React.findDOMNode(this.refs.dummyInput)
  });
});
```

My Webpack config has an `output` that looks like this:

```
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, '../sandbox', 'dist'),
  filename: 'app.js'
},
```

So the JS files are being built into a `dist` directory within my `sandbox` project. The page that uses the scripts is `sandbox/index.html`.

When I actually build the code, the Pikaday bundle is indeed generated at `sandbox/dist/2.app.js`. **BUT** the Webpack-generated loader looks for it at `sandbox/2.app.js` -- without the `dist` -- and therefore doesn't find it. So the code doesn't work.

Can any Webpack experts help me out here?

(Because of my history with Webpack, I'm guessing that this is confusion related to unclear documentation, rather than a bug -- but if you do think it is a bug, let me know and I will file an issue.)

--- MORE ---

Looks like essentially the same thing is happening if I try to use Pete Hunt's method (`require.ensure(..)`) describe [here](https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto) instead of `bundle-loader`. Again, there is a request being made to `/2.app.js` instead of the intended `/dist/2.app.js`.

So it really seems like the problem is about how to tell the loaders to look in `dist/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`publicPath`](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputpublicpath) is what you need.

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../sandbox', 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist', // absolute path to index.html
    ...
}
```